# progress 4GL / ABL How to Convert string "July 24 2015" to #06/24/2015# date(TS)?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, 4gl

I have string like 
`"July 24 2015"`  is it possible to convert this to date(TS) data type?

it would convert to something like mm/dd/YYYY  `"07/24/2015 00:00:00.000"`

Can I do that with progress 4GL?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
define variable inputString as character no-undo.
define variable monthList   as character no-undo.

monthList = "January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December".

update inputString format "x(30)".

display datetime( date(
  lookup(  entry( 1, inputString, " " ), monthList ),
  integer( entry( 2, inputString, " " )),
  integer( entry( 3, inputString, " " ))
)).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Thank you for the code. 
A different version. 
define variable inputString as character no-undo.
define variable monthList   as character no-undo.

monthList = "Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec".

//update inputString format "x(30)".
inputString = "17-Aug-2022".


display datetime( date(
  lookup(  entry( 2, inputString, "-" ), monthList ),
  integer( entry( 1, inputString, "-" )),
  integer( entry( 3, inputString, "-" ))
)).
```